# Ruby - Return duplicates in an array using hashes, is this efficient?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash, duplicates

I have solved the problem using normal loops and now using hashes, however I am not confident I used the hashes as well as I could have. Here is my code:

```
       # 1-100 whats duplicated

def whats_duplicated?(array)
    temp = Hash.new
    output = Hash.new

    # Write the input array numbers to a hash table and count them
    array.each do |element|
        if temp[element] >= 1
            temp[element] += 1
        else
            temp[element] = 1
        end
    end

    # Another hash, of only the numbers who appeared 2 or more times
    temp.each do |hash, count|
        if count > 1
            output[hash] = count
        end
    end
    # Return our sorted and formatted list as a string for screen
    output.sort.inspect
end

### Main
# array_1 is an array 1-100 with duplicate numbers
array_1 = []
for i in 0..99
    array_1[i] = i+1
end

# seed 10 random indexes which will likely be duplicates
for i in 0..9
    array_1[rand(0..99)] = rand(1..100)
end

# print to screen the duplicated numbers & their count
puts whats_duplicated?(array_1)
```

My question is really what to improve? This is a learning excercise for myself, I am practising some of the typical brain-teasers you may get in an interview and while I can do this easily using loops, I want to learn an efficient use of hashes. I re-did the problem using hashes hoping for efficiency but looking at my code I think it isn't the best it could be. Thanks to anyone who takes an interest in this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def whats_duplicated?(array)
  array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |val, hsh| hsh[val] += 1 }.select { |k,v| v > 1 }.keys
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening once the { } portion begins?


    `array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |val, hsh| hsh[val] += 1}`

Each element of array is iterated through, an object of type Hash with a value of 0 is instantiated (in an array or 100 seperate ones?) Then an operation within the { } is performed adding 1 for each instance of the number?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find duplicates in ruby, is to group the elements, and then count how many are in each group:

```
def whats_duplicated?(array)
  array.group_by { |x| x }.select { |_, xs| xs.length > 1 }.keys
end

whats_duplicated?([1,2,3,3,4,5,3,2])
# => [2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used the select part now. I will try to integrate the rest of your suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
def duplicates(array)
  counts = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = 0 }

  array.each do |number|
    counts[number] += 1
  end

  counts.select { |k,v| v > 1 }.keys
end

array = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9]

puts duplicates(array)
# => [4,6,8]
```

Some comments about your code: The block `if temp[element] == 1` seems not correct. I think that will fail if a number occurs three or more times in the array. You should at least fix it to:

```
if temp[element]       # check if element exists in hash
  temp[element] += 1   # if it does increment
else
  temp[element] = 1    # otherwise init hash at that position with `1`
end
```

Furthermore I recommend not to use the `for x in foo` syntax. Use `foo.each do |x|` instead. Hint: I like to ask in interviews about the difference between both versions.

Comment: Thanks, I have used select now. I will continue to try to improve the code!

Comment: Actually the code will work without the fix since all values greater than 1 are treated the same. So, although if an element occurs five times, the value in the hash will be 2 instead of 5, but the end result will be the same, since both 2 and 5 are greater than 1...